# How to provide list of multiple databases with one JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

Currently I need to write my own Type 2 JDBC driver. The product I am writing for supports an ODBC driver and I can connect to it using DBEaver over a JDBC-ODBC bridge. Through this bridge, it shows that multiple databases exist and I am running sql queries successfully.
To create the JDBC driver, I have implemented 4 interfaces java.sql.Driver, java.sql.Connection, java.sql.Satement, java.sql.ResultSet. But I cannot find a way to get the driver to provide information about multiple databases at the same time. I am using jdk1.6.0_16. How can I get my JDBC driver to serve multiple databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach you can take is to create different `connection`s, using different usernames, password, and/or connection properties, one for every database you need to access, and perhaps combine the information obtained from those different schemas in your java application.

As an alternative, in certain database systems, you can grant a schema/user permissions over database objects in different schemas, even in different databases: as a consequence, you could grant the necessary permissions to one schema and use that schema to access the others. Please, be aware of the possible security implications of this *super schema* approach.